# passing large data to Titanium.Utils.md5HexDigest

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to calculate md5 hash for large files ( about 60MB or more). The device, a Nexus 7 with 1GB RAM and 16GB, is not able to allocate anything more than 30MB. The code fails with java.lang.OutOfMemory exception.

And I don't find any way to add data in a piecemeal way to Titanium.Utils.md5HexDigest(). It needs the whole data at once.

Is there any way I can workaround this problem?

I have searched for any products that would help me do this on the Marketplace. But I haven't found any.

Comment: is the file actually on the device? What is the reason you want to do this? (Why I'm asking: this doesn't seem to be an operation a phone should do)

Comment: @RenePot Yes the file is on the device. I need check the md5 of the file to determine if I should download it again or not. Not really on a phone.. we are building a Digital signage app for a minix box running android  4.2.2. But I am kind of testing on a Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it was to determine wether or not to download it again. So, it comes from a server somewhere.

Instead of recalculating the `MD5`, you should have already stored that in the app when downloading the file in the first place. So just compare the stored `MD5 Hash` with the one on the server. This saves you a lot of trouble, and actually doesn't require you to recalculate. It also speeds up the app tremendously.

Comment: Lets say my connection aborted for some reason or I am restarting after a crash and I don't know if the file has been completely downloaded or not. So first I check the file size. If it is less then I resume to download the remaining bytes and append to the file. And if it is the same size then I need to calculate the MD5 hash and then compare it with the one on the server.